# How to create new quote programmatically from old order after place the order in magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, addtocart, quote

I want to create a new quote based on the old order. I can create order programmatically but not able to just add to cart product in a new quote.
I don't want to place the order. Need is only add to cart product programmatically.

Comment: you mean create new quote based on last order order??

Comment: Yes, and I successfully did :)

Comment: can you please add your solution.. ??? So other people can easy to get a solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow magento reorder functionality. E.g: *vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/AbstractController/Reorder.php*

The following line will create new quote:

```
$reorderOutput = $this->reorder->execute($order->getIncrementId(), $order->getStoreId());
```

You can open **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Reorder/Reorder.php**, where you can found more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a simple code and it works well, please take a look:

```
<!-- language: lang-php-->
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomerCartManagement
{
    /**
     * @var CartManagementInterface
     */
    private CartManagementInterface $cart;

    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository;

    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface|ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private CartRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    /**
     * @param CartManagementInterface $cart
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        CartManagementInterface $cart,
        CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param $productId
     */
    public function addProductToCart($productId)
    {
        try {
            $cartId = $this->cart->createEmptyCart();
            $cart = $this->cartRepository->get($cartId);
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
            $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject([
                'product' => $productId,
                'qty' => 1,
            ]);
            $cart->addProduct($product, $request);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: An empty cart is created but the product not added to the cart or quote. I added $productId = 1.

Comment: Did you check the logs? After executing any exception during the process should be written on the logs. Can you share some details about the product: qty, product type, stock details (MSI or default inventory), status, and anything you reckon is relevant.

Comment: Yes checked logs. there is no exception. when i am going to just print product data like name or sku then all are blanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'print product data'? Are you checking that data on product page admin panel? Or are you printing the product data of the object $product?